# How to make a website to occupy the entire element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I will specify. I have this rather simple website, on which I have three button/links which I made to diplay (with a little magic of JS) within one of it's elements (section with id "content"). It works fine and all but (and it's a big one) for some reason it only display it in a tiny window in a upper-left corner with like a scroll down bar and I can't make it to occupy the entire 'section'.

JS I've got is:

```
function load_projects() {
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="projects.html" ></object>';
        }
```

and an element :

```
<section class="box sect shadow" id="content">  
</section>
```

css for it:

```
.box {
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 600px;
    margin-right: 20%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.sect {
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

.shadow {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 11px 31px -2px rgba(120,124,125,0.61);
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 11px 31px -2px rgba(120,124,125,0.61);
    box-shadow: 10px 11px 31px -2px rgba(120,124,125,0.61);
}
```

So to summerise: I have a 'nav' element with three button/links that are being displayed within 'section' element, but instesd of occupying the whole surface of 'section' links are being displayed in a tiny, scroll-down window.
what am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not specified any styles for the object that you're adding, so it doesn't know to fill the container element.

Add the following css...

```
#content object {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't change anything other than the added object.

Comment: it did, it added to it's width, and completly ignores left margin. But it's probably because I've got it as inline-block

Comment: Without seeing an example of why this isn't working it's not possible to help, as this is the solution to the problem you posted.  Can you at least show us the css for the object?

Comment: I only specified 50px padding for it all around. But you are right. That should be a totaly different question. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: No worries - glad to help :)